# Are University Policies and Procedures in (public) Canadian universities supposed to be public?

Tags: university, legal-issues, canada, policy

I recently attempted to access the current University Policies and Procedures for a (public) Canadian university from the university's website. But when I clicked on the link to the PDF the browser popped up a login prompt, which precludes anyone without credentials from accessing this document.

My understanding is that because this university is a public institution, their policies and procedures document should be public.

Is that not the case?

Comment: While their policies may be public, the means of accessing them might be different. They are probably available otherwise through a national or provincial site.

Comment: "on the internet" is just one form of being "made public" so I do not follow your logic.